# Body overflow screen width on mobile only

Tags: html, css, mobile-phones

I am trying to create a fluid layout that adapts to different screen sizes...
It works on the desktop with no issues, but on a tablet or a cellphone the body overflows and creates a horizontal scroll bar.
[Click here you can see the problem](http://www.10elearning.com/en/projects/history.php)

I already have checked all the elements and their padings and margins, and that doesn't seam to be the issue.

Comment: Since you're not showing any of the coding, my first guess would be a fixed-width element.

Comment: It's the `.infolinksbottom` blocks causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction... it is the social media links in one of the columns...

Answer (score 1):

Used to  this css   for **desktop scroll remove**

`footer.css` **line no 55**

```
.infolinksbottom{
margin-left:5%;  // remove this line
margin-left:0;  //add this line 
padding-left:5%;  // add this line
box-sizing: border-box;  // add this line
}
```

Comment: this is css3 property and i m using to  padding . More information search to  google How to used css3 property box-sizing basically this is related to box-model Css .

Comment: I am having a similar problem in this page too: http://www.10elearning.com/en/projects/philosophy.php I fix the footer.css, but I can't find what is causing it on this page. All other pages with that footer behave as expected with no overflow.. I just going nuts...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the way css propertiese set for the class `**.bottomlong**`. You will need to manage `min-width` more precisely. Currently `min-width` is set to `120px` so that's one of the prime reason that its giving Horizontal Scrollbar. Either you get less than `120px` min-width or put `float:left;` for `.bottomlong`.

I observed you are not using `BREAKPOINTS`. The best practice would be to use breakpoints to achieve your result over different devices.

Here are few of the most commonly used break-points

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px){
    /*your css classes*/
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    /*your css classes*/
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    /*your css classes*/
}
```

You may like refer [GOOGLE DOCS FOR BREAKPOINTS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/how-to-choose-breakpoints?hl=en) for more detailed information.

Comment: Hope that worked well for you. I strongly suggest to use BREAK-POINTS instead managing responsiveness only through 100% height kind of tricks. :)